# How do i deploy .NET projects on a Linux Server(Webmin)

Tags: .net, linux, apache, mono, webmin

So,this has been bugging me for quite sometime,i tried a lot of solutions that are there on the internet and its not working out
Tried mod_mono,Mono,Docker,nginx

I can compile a Dotnet project,but i'm not able to put it onto Internet Hosting,like i can navigate to the folder which has all the files and all but the services like WebAPI and other things aren't getting triggered
Any help would be deeply appreciated,btw i have a Webmin Server Management on top of it

Answer (score -1):

Use wine or playonlinux to run your .net application on linux. It will create a window like space in linux operation system. I play counter strike in Linux using such service.

Comment: I can run my apps on the server,but im not able to deploy it on the server to make it internet hostable

Comment: why do you want to deploy your .NET application on linux as a window server is the best choice for such type of application.

Comment: My client has linux server and i don't want to write my web service in any other language :/